# Changing the focal length has no effect on the render

Tags: rendering, camera

When I change the camera's focal length, I can see that the view changes in the camera perspective but there is no change when I render the image. The object that the camera is pointed at, stays at the same size regardless of the focal length.
Also, the input field "Focal Length" has an orange background; I'm not sure if that was always the case or indicates something.

I'm pretty sure I'm selecting the right camera (there is only one), and also didn't observe this behaviour before. I must have accidentally messed up with something but I can't figure out. Any ideas?

[image: camera parameters]

Comment: The Focal Length value is orange, it means that you've already keyframed it, and the render you do take this keyframe into account, not the one you try to enter currently. Take a look into the Timeline and you should see a keyframe, simply remove it.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. I must have accidentally keyframed it, now everything is back to normal after clearing the keyframe. Thanks!